# Storing the Output while Executing ".exe" file using python is not as expected

Tags: windows

I have an executable file where i need to pass the input and get the output details. However Output can be saved in 3 formats "HTML","XML","Text" format. But by default it will save in HTML if user doesn't opt for any specific format.

I have my script which can do what i have mentioned above. But output is saving in ".HTML" . Is there any way to select the desired output options.

I used subprocess  for interacting with exe file.

```
cmd = (r'C:\Program Files\file.exe',k1)
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out = proc.communicate()
print out[0]
s= str(out[0])
print type(s)    
f2 = open(k1+'.xml','wb') #storing in html (as its taking it by default)
f2.write(s)
f2.close()
```

Comment: please correct indentation

Comment: code is executing fine without any indentation and syntax errors.